# Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement error

Tags: php, mysqli

I had a mysql query and I was converting it to mysqli(prepared statement) but I ran in to a problem which throws the below error,

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement

Mysql code

```
$random_name_generated = vpb_generate_random_name().'.jpg'; //Generated name for uploaded files or images

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_to_upload']['tmp_name'], $final_uploads_location)) {
    $check_empty_field = mysql_query("select * from `vpb_uploads` where `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($username))."'  and `firstname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string("")."' and `lastname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string("")."'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($check_empty_field) < 1) {
        mysql_query("insert into `vpb_uploads` values('', '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."', '', '', '".mysql_real_escape_string($random_name_generated)."', '', '', '', '', '".mysql_real_escape_string(date("d-m-Y"))."')");

        $identity = "image_one";
    } else {
        $get_empty_field = mysql_fetch_array($check_empty_field);
        $image_one = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_one"]);
        $image_two = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_two"]);
        $image_three = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_three"]);
        $image_four = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_four"]);
        $image_five = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_five"]);
        global $identity;
```

The below is what I tried even though it didn't work. I already knew it won't work but I wanted to try it myself before asking a question. And the error is coming from the `$get_empty_field = $stmt->bind_result($stmt);`

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_to_upload']['tmp_name'], $final_uploads_location)) {
    $firstname = '""';
    $lastname = '""';
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select * from `vpb_uploads` where `username` = ?  and `firstname` = ? and `lastname` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $firstname, $lastname);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if ($stmt->num_rows < 1) {
        $date = 'date("d-m-Y")';
        $image_2 = "''";
        $image_3 = "''";
        $image_4 = "''";
        $image_5 = "''";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("insert into `vpb_uploads` (`username`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `image_one`, `image_two`, `image_three`, `image_four`, `image_five`, `date`) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('sssssssss', $username, $firstname, $lastname, $random_name_generated, $image_2, $image_3, $image_4, $image_5, $date);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        $identity = "image_one";
    } else {
        $get_empty_field = $stmt->bind_result($stmt);
        $image_one = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_one"]);
        $image_two = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_two"]);
        $image_three = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_three"]);
        $image_four = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_four"]);
        $image_five = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_five"]);
        global $identity;
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to change

```
$get_empty_field = $stmt->bind_result($stmt);
```

To

```
$get_empty_field = $stmt->bind_result($field1, $field2, $field3);
```

The number of `$fieldx` variables being equal to the number of fields that are selected. If you don't know how many there are, use this:

```
  // Throw an exception if the result metadata cannot be retrieved
  if (!$meta = $stmt->result_metadata())
  {
    throw new Exception($stmt->error);
  }

  // The data array
  $data = array();

  // The references array
  $refs = array();

  // Iterate over the fields and set a reference
  while ($name = $meta->fetch_field())
  {
    $refs[] =& $data[$name->name];
  }

  // Free the metadata result
  $meta->free_result();

  // Throw an exception if the result cannot be bound
  if (!call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $refs))
  {
    throw new Exception($stmt->error);
  }
```

And then you access the result, after fetching, with `$data['field']`;

Comment: I changed to what you said but still it throws the warning.

Comment: How many fields are in the table? How many variables have you passed to the `bind_result` function?

Comment: There are 9 fields in the table and I passed 3 variables.

Comment: I did make an edit to fix an error in my example, so you might want to copy my code again. Also, if there are 10 fields then you need to pass 10 variables (when using `SELECT *`).

Comment: oh I have no idea how to fix it, can you tell me how can I make it show the error? I mean like something like mysqli->error(); if it was a mysqli error.

Comment: You fix it by passing 10 variables instead of 3, or by using the code example I gave.

Comment: so I will put the code you gave me instead of $get_empty_field = $stmt->bind_result($field1, $field2, $field3);. right?

Comment: Yes, and then you access the result using `$data['image_one']`.

Comment: hmm tried everything I could but no luck. I have to use the old mysql then.

Comment: Post the code you have now in your question. Do *not* go back to `mysql`. It's deprecated and will be removed in the future.