# mysql php: How to bind result with the same recurring variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to bind a recurring variable. What I am trying to achieve is that:

1. Do a check before submission
2. Check in column 'message' and 'user' if this two exist together. If yes than true
3. Or check if only 'user' (a particular user) exist.
4. As you can see im binding the variable 'user' twice.
5. If item 2 or 3 are true, than $search_data->fetch() will be more than zero and will echo an error and prevent submission

> Problem:

1. Problem is I have encountered an error saying `Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement`
2. IF i remove the bind_result it works but i am wondering what effect would that have? Advice and help greatly appreciated

Note:
I am using $username_form twice in the bind_param

Below is my code:

```
$search_data=$db->prepare("SELECT message,user FROM test_table_1 WHERE (message=? AND user=?) OR (user=?)");
    $search_data->bind_param("sss", $message_form, $username_form, $username_form);

    $search_data->execute();
    $search_data->bind_result($result1,$result2,$result3);
    if($search_data->fetch() >0){
        //echo "<script>alert('Entry already exist')</script>";
        $search_data->close();
        echo 'Error_duplicate';
    }
    else {
        $insert_data=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO test_table_1(message,user) VALUES (?, ?)");

        $insert_data->bind_param("ss", $message_form, $username_form);
        $insert_data->execute();


        if ($insert_data->affected_rows >0){
            echo "New record created successfully";

        } else {
            echo "Not inserted";
          }
        $search_data->close();
        $insert_data->close(); //close prepare statement


    }
    $db->close();
```

> Update1:
>   I am aware of a similiar thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693135/warning-mysqli-stmtbind-result-number-of-bind-variables-doesnt-match-numb) however as I have stated the above problem i have tried binding it to three variables and it did not work. would like advice on that.

Comment: @Your Common Sense Yes i have checked out that thread and bind my variables to three seperate ones as you can see from the code and it doesnt work . Would like advice on that.

Comment: fields are not parameters. you have 2 fields selected, not 3

Comment: @YourCommonSense if i dont bind my result but still do a if check `$insert_data->affected_rows` it still valid why is that so?